# How to keep connection to SIP server in background using flutter_webrtc?

Tags: flutter, sip, voip, flutter-webrtc

I'm using `flutter_webrtc` and `sip_ua` packages to implement VoIP calls. The flow of registration on the SIP server is as follows,

> When the user opens the app, the client(App) is registered on the server with the required credentials.

**What do I want to achieve?**

I want the client should be registered, even when the app is in the `background`. The purpose of this functionality is to enable the client(App) to receive Calls, even when the app is in the background.

I want to know if such functionality is possible, and how!

Comment: You generally aren't going to get a lot of spare cpu while in the background.  In fact, the OS may just kill your app if it wants the space.  The only reliable action is to send an FCM which can alert the user to take an action, including intrinsically launching your app again.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, I'am doing the same things using flutter incoming call kit, sip ua and FCM. But, I can't find the solution to keep SIP connection still alive although user exit the app.
The possible way you can achieve is writing the app with native.
I tried POC using open source like https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

it can run in the background to achieve incoming calls.